# Get ajax sending data on nodejs server

Tags: node.js, ajax, request

I had simple ajax request(request from external server)

```
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8001/startApps",
                data: 'sss',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('AllOk');
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('err: '+XMLHttpRequest.status);
                }
            });
```

how i could get this data : 'sss' on node js server

```
app.post('/startApps', function (req,res,next) {
    console.log(req.body);//I trying req.data, req.params req.query etc ..
    res.send('Ok');
})
```

Comment: What does it return in the console?

Comment: @YanetPedraza req.data, req.body return undefined. req.query and req.params return {}

Comment: Did you check if you put your body-parser code above all the routes

Comment: @YanetPedraza bodyParser required `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check body-parser in express:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express(),
    port    = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 8080;

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: I forgot that that wasnt express project and i should to write `app.use(bodyParser());`

Answer (score 1):

By default `$.ajax` defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content type to send to server. In your case i hope you are sending plain data. Hence you should use `contentType` as `text/plain` to send data and fetch it on server as plain text.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://localhost:8001/startApps",
            data: 'sss',
            contentType:'text/plain',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('AllOk');
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('err: '+XMLHttpRequest.status);
            }
        });
```

Comment: i add this line but i still couldnt get data on server(

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if it works

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8001/startApps",
            data: 'sss',
            dataType : "text",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('err: '+XMLHttpRequest.status);
            }
});

app.post('/startApps', function (req,res,next) {
    res.send('Ok');
})
```

Comment: its work. I cat get response data from server. But how i could get request data on server?

Comment: Are you using bodyParser?

Comment: bodyPArser required `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');`

Comment: @ItsMyLife - Your data value `sss` needs a key so like: `data: {key: 'sss'}`, then you can access it using `req.body.key`

Comment: Try to put these lines above all your routes in your app.js file to see if it works `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.use(bodyParser());`